# How to push images to github container registry hosted in company servers

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, package, registry

I am building github workflow, which creates docker image from quarkus application. I want to push this image into github registry. Since github enterprise is hosted on our servers, I suppose URL for the registry is not docker.pkg.github.com or ghcr.io.
I am getting this error.

```
Run docker push docker.pkg.github.com/org/repo:a52e19e2e6cf0ac6c7d7cd80025833f784ecbd29
The push refers to a repository [docker.pkg.github.com/org/repo]
20c1982dc64e: Preparing
c5547f46cb3c: Preparing
883ad731c7dd: Preparing
e9c843895906: Preparing
Error: Status 404 trying to push repository org/repo: "404 page not found\n"
```

How should the URL for such a case look like or how should I push images into registry. Thank you

Comment: Did you login? https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry
It also looks as though your image name is `repo`, is this intentional? Also, can you verify whether you have tagged the image as part of the build step?

Comment: @TheQueenIsDead yes I did login with use of GITHUB_TOKEN. I also tagged the image, but I am not sure about the format, that I should use because of kind of special case

Comment: I used org/repo for the placeholder prupose